# Match value after semicolon without including comma

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match the string after the semicolon while not including the comma, i.e. I am specifically looking for the values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, etc.

Here is the input:

`C07KTL89290003;1,C07KTL89290003,1;2,C07KTL89290003,0;3,C07KTL89290003,0;4,C07KTL89290003,0;5,C07KTL89290003,0;6,C07KTL89290003,0;7,C07KTL89290003,0;8,C07KTL89290003,0;9,C07KTL89290003,0;10,C07KTL89290003,0;11,C07KTL89290003,0;12,C07KTL89290003,0;13,C07KTL89290003,0;14,C07KTL89290003,0;15,C07KTL89290003,0;16,C07KTL89290003,0;17,C07KTL89290003,0;18,C07KTL89290003,0;19,C07KTL89290003,0;20,C07KTL89290003,0;21,C07KTL89290003,0;22,C07KTL89290003,0;23,C07KTL89290003,0;24,C07KTL89290003,0;25,C07KTL89290003,0;26,C07KTL89290003,0;27,C07KTL89290003,0;28,C07KTL89290003,0;29,C07KTL89290003,0;30,C07KTL89290003,0;31,C07KTL89290003,0;32,C07KTL89290003,0;33,C07KTL89290003,0;34,C07KTL89290003,0;35,C07KTL89290003,0;36,C07KTL89290003,0;37,C07KTL89290003,0;38,C07KTL89290003,0;39,C07KTL89290003,0;40,C07KTL89290003,0`

The expression I am using right now is

```
\d+[,]+[^,]+[^,0-2]
```

However this is returning the number after a `;`, a comma and the substring till the next comma.

Can someone please help me modify my expression to match only the digits after the semicolon while not including the comma?

Comment: I get [many more](https://regex101.com/r/v8tOjX/1) than 2 values.

Comment: Which value do you want to match?

Comment: Please include a sample list of desired matches. It's hard to tell whether you want `1C07KTL892900031` or `C07KTL89290003`

Comment: I am specifically looking for the values 1,2,3,4,5,6....etc

Comment: So use `(?<=;)\d+`, see https://regex101.com/r/soju5C/1

Comment: your solution does not return values that are bigger than 9 for instance the value 10 is only showing the 1 being matched

Comment: @ScottRuiter [**MY** solution](https://regex101.com/r/soju5C/1) returns all of them. What is your programming language?

Comment: C# when I am testing in regexr it is not matching double digit values

Comment: If you use C#, forget about regexr and what it shows. Use `var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=;)\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);`

Comment: And [here is a .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3b%29%5cd%2b&i=C07KTL89290003%3b1%2cC07KTL89290003%2c1%3b2%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b3%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b4%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b5%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b6%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b7%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b8%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b9%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b10%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b11%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b12%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b13%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b14%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b15%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b16%2cC07KTL89290003%2c0%3b17%2cC).

Comment: I had the ungreedy flag used once I removed this  Wiktor Stribiżew your solution is correct

Comment: That is what I say about the online testers: always use a compatible one when testing your patterns. .NET regex does not support greediness swapping modifier.

Comment: Posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272283/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, C# in your case, you may use

```
(?<=;)\d+
```

Or, if you must specify that a valid match is only when a comma follows the digits:

```
(?<=;)\d+(?=,)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3B%29%5Cd%2B&i=C07KTL89290003%3B1%2CC07KTL89290003%2C1%3B2%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B3%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B4%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B5%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B6%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B7%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B8%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B9%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B10%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B11%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B12%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B13%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B14%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B15%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B16%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B17%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B18%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B19%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B20%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B21%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B22%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B23%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B24%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B25%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B26%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B27%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B28%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B29%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B30%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B31%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B32%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B33%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B34%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B35%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B36%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B37%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B38%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B39%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0%3B40%2CC07KTL89290003%2C0) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<=;)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `;` to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=,)` - (not really necessary here) a positive lookahead that requires a `,` to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

C# snippet:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=;)\d+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\d+[,]+\K[^,]+[^,0-2]
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGYjIZ/4)